# Prepending elements in front of a line

Tags: notepad++

I would like to prepend a word or spaces in front of each line. Is this possible?

so essentially I want To add "ho" before every line

```
firstline
secondline
thirdline
```

I would like it to become

```
hofirstline
hosecondline
hothirdline
```

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: To clarify... are you looking for (a) an existing Notepad++ Plugin, (b) guidance on how to develop one yourself, (c) guidance on how to write an app that will do that to a text file, or (d) something else?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the replace functionality:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
then:

Find what: `^`
Replace with: `ho`
then clic on <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

another way:

Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and drag the mouse at the begining of all lines. Then type `ho`.